# Sort Main-List by property of Sublist in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Currently i have the following structure of my classes:

```
 public class StoreElement
{
    [Display(Name="ID")]
    public int StoreElementId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "RegalID")]
    public string StoreElementCode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Regal")]
    public string Storage { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Ebene")]
    public string Level { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Fach")]
    public string Shelf { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "ESL Tag")]
    public string ESLTagId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="ESL Layout Template")]
    public string ESLLayoutValue { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Eingelagertes Material")]
    public List<Material> Materials { get; set; }
```

}

And this class:

```
    public class Material
{
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int MaterialId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Materialnummer")]
    public int? MaterialNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Auftragsnummer")]
    public int? OrderNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Eingelagert")]
    public bool? IsStored { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Einlagerdatum")]
    public DateTime StoredAt { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Auslagerdatum")]
    public DateTime OutsourcedAt { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Liefertermin")]
    public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Priorisiertes Material")]
    public bool PriorityMaterial { get; set; }



    public int? StoreElementId { get; set; }
    public StoreElement StoreElement { get; set; }
}
```

A StoreElement can hold a List of Materials. The class Materials contains a property which is a date. Now i would like to order the Storage-Location List by the subproperty date of a list of materials.

I tried something in linq like that:

```
var myOrderdStorageLocationsByDeliveryDateOfMaterialsSublist = this.MyDatabaseContext.StorageLocations.Include(x=>x.Materials).OrderBy(x=>x.Materials.OrderBy(y=>y.DeliveryDate)).ToList();
```

But this throws an exception that says "Failed to compare two elements in the array"

Comment: Can you provide example of order how exacly you want it eg. Element A(with materials cba) then Element B(with Material cde)

Comment: Which Date value from `Materials` do you want to use to order by? Which LINQ to EF are you using: EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, you need some value from Materials. And OrderBy won't return it.
I would recommend you to get a particular value for sorting StoreElements based on what logic you need: `Min`, `Max` or `Average` for example.

```cs
var myOrderdStorageLocationsByDeliveryDateOfMaterialsSublist = this.MyDatabaseContext.StorageLocations
.Include(x=>x.Materials)
.OrderBy(x=>x.Materials.Min(y=>y.DeliveryDate))
.ToList();
```

Comment: Could you explain this in more detail? Why should i use Min? I would like to order the main List of StorageLocations by a property of the sublist of materials. If i try it like you said i get this exception ""Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Because you need some particular value of the property, you'd like to use. Otherwise, in your case, it tries to sort by an array value, because inner OrderBy will return it. And it doesn't know, how to compare two elements that are arrays.

Comment: Or you should pass your own comparer as the third argument to the top OrderBy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_OrderBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Collections_Generic_IComparer___1__